# Function which codomain is a set

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a bijection. If $B$ is a set, does this imply that $A$ is a set as well?

My confusion came from the proof of Yoneda Lemma. You prove that natural transformations from hom(A,−) functor to given one (denote by F) are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of F(A). I don't see why these natural transformations form a set.

Comment: You should add this information to the question. Otherwise, it sounds like a question on a totally different level ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you talk about a *function* $f:A\rightarrow B$, you know that $A$ and $B$ are sets. That's how functions are defined: mapping elements from sets to sets.  The function being a bijection, injection, etc. has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider here.

The first, as Bram28 wrote, if you define a function as a set, then it is generally one of the consequences of any reasonable set theory, that the domain and range of a function are also sets.

The second, is the Axiom [schema] of Replacement in the context of $\sf ZF$. This schema says that if $\varphi$ is a formula which defines a function, then when we apply it to a set, the range is also a set. In other words, if we can describe a function, then it is a function.

It might be of interest to note that a lot of category theory can be developed in $\sf ZC$, rather than in $\sf ZFC$, which is more-or-less the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ with the Axiom of Replacement omitted. So Replacement does not come into play that often when it comes to mathematics. But as an axiom, Replacement is both natural, and ensures that one does not need to worry about certain things being sets (for example, Replacement ensures that $\{\mathcal P^n(\Bbb N)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is indeed a set, and we cannot prove that without using Replacement).

---

Let me finish by making a terminological remark. In categorical contexts a function is often a triple of domain, co-domain and graph; but in set theory a function is usually just the graph and the co-domain is an external property to the function. This has some benefits, of course, but it might not always correspond with whatever it is you're thinking about.

Now let's examine the question in both cases:

1. If a function is a triplet $(A,B,f)$, then by definition it can only be the case that $A$ and $B$ are sets. If you want to talk about functions with domain or codomain being proper classes, then one needs either a meta-theory capable of doing so, e.g. working with universes, or a more careful way of coding the ordered triplet.

   But the working assumption would be that the codomain is by definition a set.
2. If a function is just a graph, then the codomain is not intrinsic to the function, and it can be anything which contains the range of the function. Even more so, if a function is just a collection of ordered pairs, then it makes it much easier to talk about class-functions. And then it is easy to find a function which has a domain which is a proper class, but its range is a set (e.g. any constant function), and therefore the codomain can be a set but the domain is a class.

   Of course, this means that we treat a function in a broader sense, as to allow functions to have domain or range which are proper classes. And in any case under the Axiom of Replacement a function from a proper class into a set will never be injective.